# Calculate stock available by adding column on the basis color

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate stock in sql. I've 4 table product, size, purchase and sales. product table is

```
+----+------------------+
| id | product_name     | 
+----+------------------+
| 1  | apple            | 
|----|------------------|
| 2  |banana            | 
|----|------------------|
| 3  |mango             | 
+----+------------------+
```

Now color table

```
+----+------------------+
| id |   color_name     | 
+----+------------------+
| 1  |   dark           | 
|----|------------------|
| 2  |   light          | 
+----|------------------+
```

purchase table is

```
+-------+-------------+
| id    | quantity    |color
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   15        |dark
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   10        |light
+-------+-------------+
|   2   |   5         |dark
+-------+-------------+
|   3   |   25        |light
+-------+-------------+
```

and sales table is

```
+-------+-------------+
| id    | quantity    |color
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   5         |dark
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   5         |light
+-------+-------------+
|   2   |   5         |dark
+-------+-------------+
|   3   |   5         |light
+-------+-------------+
```

Purchase and sales table have foreign key id references id of product table. Now I'm trying to calculate stock available i.e. difference of purchase and sales in below format on the basis of color too

```
+----+------------------+-------------+
| id | product_name     | quantity    |color
+----+------------------+-------------+
| 1  | apple            |    10       |dark
|----|------------------|-------------|
| 1  | apple            |    5        |light
|----|------------------|-------------|
| 2  |banana            |    0        |dark
|----|------------------|-------------|
| 3  |mango             |    20       |light
+----+------------------+-------------+
```

I have following script which i have tried :

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.Name,
       Purchase.purchaseQty - sales.salseQty AS totalQty

FROM Product p
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT purchase.id,
               SUM(purchase.quantity) purchaseQty

        FROM purchase
        WHERE purchase.id = p.id
        GROUP BY
            purchase.id
) Purchase
     OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT sales.id,
                SUM(sales.quantity) salseQty
         FROM sales
         WHERE sales.id = p.id
         GROUP BY
             sales.id
) sales
;
```

Comment: color is a column in purchase & Sales tables? or you just mentioned? If it is a column then you need foreign key relationship with colors table.

Comment: what you have tried ??

Comment: @YogeshSharma someone help me with this solution SELECT p.id,p.Name,Purchase.purchaseQty-sales.salseQty as totalQty
FROM Product p
OUTER APPLY(
         SELECT  purchase.id, SUM(purchase.quantity) purchaseQty
         FROM purchase 
         where purchase.id= p.id
         GROUP BY purchase.id
)Purchase
OUTER APPLY(
         SELECT  sales.id, SUM(sales.quantity) salseQty
         FROM sales
         where sales.id= p.id
         GROUP BY sales.id
)sales

Comment: @ShakeerMirza color is column in purchase and sales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
select P.id, Pr.product_name,
       case when S.quantity is null then P.quantity
            else P.quantity - S.quantity end as quantity,
       P.color from purchase as P
left join sales AS S on (P.id = S.id and P.color = S.color)
join product AS Pr on Pr.id = P.id
```

Comment: this query won't show available quantity if sales is not added

Comment: I added sales :)

Comment: what if sales table is empty now purchase table should be available quantity